# nginx - proxy_pass on user_agent

Tags: nginx, http-headers, proxypass

I have a SPA site, where I need to load the appropriate `<meta>` tags for each subpage, but it is not that easy from the subpages themselves so I made a separate address where Facebook or Twitter bots can download the appropriate OpenGraph values. It looks like this:

**Original URL**: `http://website.com/contents/1`
**Route with OG tags for this URL**: `http://website.com/og/contents/1`

I want to use `proxy_pass` for this, taking into account only the specific`User-Agent`, however, the following configuration does not work, i.e. there is no redirection:

```
    location /contents {
        resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off valid=5m;

        if ($http_user_agent ~* ("(facebookexternalhit)\/(.*)|(Twitterbot)\/(.*)")) {
            proxy_pass http://$host:8080/open-graph$request_uri;
        }
    }
```

Anyone see where is bad?

Answer (score 1):

At first, when you need some string in your nginx config, you can use single or double quotes or don't use them at all (unless your string contains some special chars like spaces, curly brackets etc.) In your case nginx assumes that you don't use any quotes (because you string start with round bracket), so regex string processed by nginx is `("(facebookexternalhit)\/(.*)|(Twitterbot)\/(.*)")` including round brackets and double quotes.  It won't match any user agent unless it contains `"facebookexternalhit/..."` or `"twitterbot/..."` substrings **with the double quotes**.

In the second place, you don't need so many captures (in fact you don't need them at all cause you don't use them later). These captures make nginx spend some additional resources while matching the string against the regex (this isn't what you want on a high-load system). The following block should be work as you expected (note that the `/` symbol does not need to be escaped, although escaping it won't break the regex):

```
    if ($http_user_agent ~* (facebookexternalhit|twitterbot)/) {
        proxy_pass http://$host:8080/open-graph$request_uri;
    }
```

However, this isn't a good solution. It is better to [avoid `if` constructions](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) unless you use only [`ngx_http_rewrite_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) directives inside the `if` block. In our case nginx will create two configurations - first one will be used if User-Agent string matches the regex, the second one will be used if it doesn't. I highly recommend not to use the `if` construction here. You can use the [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) translation instead:

```
map $http_user_agent $og_prefix {
    ~*(facebookexternalhit|twitterbot)/  /open-graph;
}

server {
    ...
    location /contents {
        resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off valid=5m;
        proxy_pass http://$host:8080$og_prefix$request_uri;
    }
    ...
}
```

Value of the `$og_prefix` variable will be `/open-graph` if User-Agent string match the regex or an empty string otherwise.